# How to transform/animate a menu icon in CSS?

Tags: html, css, animation, sass

I am working on a CSS animation that should look similar to [this](https://codepen.io/roydigerhund/pen/ZQmbNm) and I am almost [there](https://codepen.io/phantazee/pen/Xzqodz), but I don't know how to get it work correctly.
For everyone who cannot or doesn't want to view the links:
Using CSS I want an animation that transforms a three bar menu icon into an X. I can make the "bars" overlap and rotate, but the strokes are far from being symmetrical.

this is my code:
HTML:

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="centerized">    
  <div class="bar1"> </div>
  <div class="bar2"> </div>
  <div class="bar3"> </div>      
 </div> 
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
@keyframes ani1{
 0% {margin-bottom: 16%;} 
 50% {margin-bottom: none; transform: translate(0, 20px);} 
 100% {margin-bottom: none; transform: rotate(30deg);}
}

@keyframes ani2{
 0% {margin-bottom: 16%; opacity: 1;} 
 75% {margin-bottom: none; opacity: 0;} 
 100% {margin-bottom: none; opacity: 0;} 
}

@keyframes ani3{
 0% {margin-bottom: 16%;} 
 50% {margin-bottom: none; transform: translate(0px, -20px);} 
 100% {margin-bottom: none; transform: rotate(-30deg);} 
}
```

Since I believe the fault lies within the way I positioned the elements during the animation I am including this part. To see the whole code I suggest to click on the link above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added the CSS's to your html to make that animation. I guess you want the effect to be on hover as in your codepen:

```css
.You-need-this-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  margin-top: -200px;
  margin-left: -200px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  background: #3FAF82;
  color: #fff;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.centerized {
  width: 80px;
  height: 52px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 50;
}

.centerized .bar1,
.centerized .bar2,
.centerized .bar3 {
  height: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -webkit-transition: background-color .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: background-color .2s ease-in-out;
}

.centerized .bar1 {
  -webkit-animation: animate-line-1-rev .7s ease-in-out;
  animation: animate-line-1-rev .7s ease-in-out;
}

.centerized .bar2 {
  margin: 14px 0;
  -webkit-animation: animate-line-2-rev .7s ease-in-out;
  animation: animate-line-2-rev .7s ease-in-out;
}

.centerized .bar3 {
  -webkit-animation: animate-line-3-rev .7s ease-in-out;
  animation: animate-line-3-rev .7s ease-in-out;
}

.centerized:hover .bar1,
.centerized:hover .bar2,
.centerized:hover .bar3 {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.centerized:hover .bar1,
.centerized:hover .bar2,
.centerized:hover .bar3 {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.centerized:hover .bar1 {
  -webkit-animation: animate-line-1 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.3, 1, 0.7, 1) forwards;
  animation: animate-line-1 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.3, 1, 0.7, 1) forwards;
}

.centerized:hover .bar2 {
  -webkit-animation: animate-line-2 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.3, 1, 0.7, 1) forwards;
  animation: animate-line-2 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.3, 1, 0.7, 1) forwards;
}

.centerized:hover .bar3 {
  -webkit-animation: animate-line-3 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.3, 1, 0.7, 1) forwards;
  animation: animate-line-3 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.3, 1, 0.7, 1) forwards;
}

.no-animation {
  -webkit-animation: none !important;
  animation: none !important;
}

@-webkit-keyframes animate-line-1 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotate(0deg);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 22px, 0) rotate(0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 22px, 0) rotate(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 22px, 0) rotate(45deg);
    transform: translate3d(0, 22px, 0) rotate(45deg);
  }
}

@keyframes animate-line-1 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotate(0deg);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 22px, 0) rotate(0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 22px, 0) rotate(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 22px, 0) rotate(45deg);
    transform: translate3d(0, 22px, 0) rotate(45deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes animate-line-2 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    transform: scale(0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes animate-line-2 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    transform: scale(0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes animate-line-3 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotate(0deg);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -22px, 0) rotate(0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -22px, 0) rotate(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -22px, 0) rotate(135deg);
    transform: translate3d(0, -22px, 0) rotate(135deg);
  }
}

@keyframes animate-line-3 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotate(0deg);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -22px, 0) rotate(0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -22px, 0) rotate(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -22px, 0) rotate(135deg);
    transform: translate3d(0, -22px, 0) rotate(135deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes animate-line-1-rev {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 22px, 0) rotate(45deg);
    transform: translate3d(0, 22px, 0) rotate(45deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 22px, 0) rotate(0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 22px, 0) rotate(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotate(0deg);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotate(0deg);
  }
}

@keyframes animate-line-1-rev {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 22px, 0) rotate(45deg);
    transform: translate3d(0, 22px, 0) rotate(45deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 22px, 0) rotate(0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 22px, 0) rotate(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotate(0deg);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotate(0deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes animate-line-2-rev {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    transform: scale(0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes animate-line-2-rev {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    transform: scale(0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes animate-line-3-rev {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -22px, 0) rotate(135deg);
    transform: translate3d(0, -22px, 0) rotate(135deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -22px, 0) rotate(0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -22px, 0) rotate(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotate(0deg);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotate(0deg);
  }
}

@keyframes animate-line-3-rev {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -22px, 0) rotate(135deg);
    transform: translate3d(0, -22px, 0) rotate(135deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -22px, 0) rotate(0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -22px, 0) rotate(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotate(0deg);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotate(0deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="You-need-this-container">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="centerized">
      <div class="bar1"> </div>
      <div class="bar2"> </div>
      <div class="bar3"> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```